# What is equivalent of Long data type in PostgreSQL?

Tags: java, postgresql

I want to know what's the equivalent of `Long` data type in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html) it looks like `bigint` is your friend, with a range of -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807.

Answer (score 19):

Should be a bigint

bigint  8 bytes large-range integer -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807

From here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html

Comment: you are right but bigint cannot be casted to long, so what is the solution then ?

Comment: @sword101: bigint in postgresql should be extracted from the ResultSet with the getLong() method- not getBigDecimal(). "bigint" isn't a java type, "long" isn't a postgresql type, so what you just said doesn't quite make sense.