# ClassCastException: Integer cannot be cast to Long, while trying to iterate over entity IDs

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have following method in my service:

```
public Set<BoardCard> moveHoldedCardsToNewBoard(Board newBoard, Board prevBoard) {
        Set<BoardCard> boardCards = new HashSet<>();
        if (prevBoard != null) {
            List<Long> holdedCardIds = getExcludedCardIds(prevBoard);
            for (Long item: holdedCardIds) {

            }
    }
```

When I want to loop the `holdedCardIds` list, I received: **java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long**  in this place -> `for (Long item: holdedCardIds) {`

My getExcludedCardIds() looks like:

```
@Override
public List<Long> getExcludedCardIds(Board board) {

        return boardCardRepository.getExcludedCardIds(board.getId());
    }
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface BoardCardRepository extends JpaRepository<BoardCard, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<BoardCard> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT bc.card_id FROM boards_cards bc WHERE bc.board_id =:boardId AND bc.on_hold=true", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Long> getExcludedCardIds(@Param("boardId") Long boardId);
}
```

Entites:

```
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "graph.BoardCard", attributeNodes = {})
@Table(name = "boards_cards")
public class BoardCard implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9019060375256960701L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private BoardCardId id = new BoardCardId();

}
@Embeddable
public class BoardCardId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3630484760647866357L;

    @ManyToOne
    private Board board;

    @ManyToOne
    private Card card;
}

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "boards")
    public class Board extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
        @Id
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "boards_id_seq", sequenceName = "boards_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "boards_id_seq")
        private Long id;
}




 @Entity    
   @Table(name = "cards")     
   public class Card extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

                @Id
                @SequenceGenerator(name = "cards_id_seq", sequenceName = "cards_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
                @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "cards_id_seq")
                private Long id;
}
```

In my POSTGRES schema.sql the BoardCard entity is defined, as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS boards_cards(
                board_id INTEGER,
                card_id INTEGER,
                on_hold BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
                CONSTRAINT pk_user_card PRIMARY KEY (board_id, card_id),
                FOREIGN KEY(board_id) REFERENCES boards(id),
                FOREIGN KEY(card_id) REFERENCES cards(id)
            );
```

I have found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245220/whats-equivalent-to-long-data-type-in-postgresql) , that equivalent of LONG type in postgresql is `bigint` . But, If I try to use it, how it will affect on the performance side of my app?

So, tell how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37111445/spring-data-jpa-classcastexception-integer-cannot-be-cast-to-long). The solution is to use **JPQL query** instead of  SQL query.

Refactored repository:

```
@Repository
public interface BoardCardRepository extends JpaRepository<BoardCard, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<BoardCard> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT id.card.id FROM BoardCard WHERE id.board.id = :boardId AND onHold = true")
    List<Long> getExcludedCardIds(@Param("boardId") Long boardId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(long) can be casted into (int), and (int) can be casted to (long)
```

However,

```
(Long) **cannot** be casted into (Integer)
```

and vice versa, as they are not primitives. Same goes for the `bigint`

This is your underlying problem, though I'm not sure where in your program it is causing the cast.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8), this problem can be solved just by transforming your list of `Integer` objects into one contained with the same values, in `long` that will then be autoboxed by java.

```
getExcludedCardIds(prevBoard).stream
                             .mapToLong(x -> x).collect(Collectors.toList);
```