# Spring Data JPA ClassCastException: Integer cannot be cast to Long

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

In my Spring Data application I ran into the similar problem described here [ClassCastException: Integer cannot be cast to Long, while trying to iterate over entity IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37105225/classcastexception-integer-cannot-be-cast-to-long-while-trying-to-iterate-over)

This my entity:

```
@Table(name = "users")
public class User extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5088960286161030648L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "users_id_seq", sequenceName = "users_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "users_id_seq")
    private Long id;
...
}
```

and Spring Data Repository method:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT u.user_id FROM users u WHERE u.game_id =:gameId", nativeQuery = true)
List<Long> getGameIds(@Param("gameId") Long gameId);
```

which is going to return List of Long type but after execution returns List of Integer and application fails with

`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long`

How to tell Spring Data or JPA return List of `Long`(not `Integer`) in the result list ?

I don't want to cast values(Integer to Long) in run-time.

Also, the main criterion of my application is performance so is it a good idea to switch my IDs from `Long` to `Integer` in all my entities ? Is it a good practice to use `Integer` instead of `Long` in JPA for entity ID ?

**UPDATED**

I use PostgreSQL

In case of:

`user_id INTEGER` I'm receiving - `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long`

`user_id BIGINT` I'm receiving - `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long`

Comment: Did you try to use not native query but JPQL, something like "select id from User where ..."?

Comment: Check the database type of the column for entityId, use appropriate type for column and compatible type for attribute in java class, then this won't appear.

Comment: which DB are you using

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL. I have updated my question and added more info about my `user_id` datatype.

Comment: @Stan, JPQL works fine, thanks ! Is any chance to get it working with a native query also ?

Comment: Have you tried to include "resultClass=Long.class" in your @Query annotation?

Comment: @RubioRic, I can be wrong but looks like `@Query` annotation doesn't support `resultClass` attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is when you are using native query `Long` class doesn't corellate with your database type — getLong doesn't work there. So you should do one of the following

1. Change type in db and in app to BigInteger (if integer is not enough for your needs)
2. Change type in db and in app to Integer (if it's enough for your needs)
3. Remove nqtiveQuery attribute and use clear JPQL.